# In React-Native Application, a variable can be used without first being defined. Why is that?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

Here's a very simple example of react-native code:

```
import React from "react";

console.log("Hello", tony);
const tony = 313;

export default function App() {
  return null;
}
```

As you can see, I'm referencing a variable "tony" before it was defined.  In ES6 that should be an error and throw a ReferenceError.

But why does it work when I create a react-native app?

The console displays:  Hello undefined

Comment: "In ES6 that should be an error and throw a ReferenceError." - why is that?

Comment: Because you access a const or a let variable before it is defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get the same behaviour. Doesn't work in React, works in RN.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works in react-native?  It really should not!!!